# JavaScript ES2015 dynamic inheritance with browserify and babelify

Tags: javascript, inheritance, browserify, babeljs

Is there a way to do dynamic inheritance with ES2015 with Browserify and Babelify ?

I need to wrap a class "Predecessor" with extra functionality "Constructor", and I don't know what the Predecessor is going to be, so I don't know the number of arguments or anything about its execution.

Normally, for dynamic inheritance in JS, I would do:

```
function Constructor() {
  Predecessor.apply(this, arguments); // <<-- this is what I'm trying to do.
}
Constructor.prototype = Object.create(Predecessor.prototype);
Constructor.prototype.constructor = Constructor;
```

When I try to use ES2015:

```
class Constructor extends Predecessor {
  constructor() {
    super(arguments);
  }
}
```

`super(arguments)` gets transformed to:

```
var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Singleton).call(this, args));
```

so, `Predecessor` gets executed something like if you did: `new Predecessor([arguments]);` (array within array).

1. I tried removing super and use `Predecessor.apply(this, arguments);` directly but it throws an error (`super` must be called). Also, I don't want to execute the Predecessor twice.
2. I tried `super.apply(arguments)` out of frustration, and it, of course, doesn't work (throws a bundle error).
3. I even tried eval (knowing all of its side effects) with no success an a way too complex solution to even like it.

I don't want to force the developer to say all the arguments will be enclosed in an array, so:

4. My last resource has been to assume a maximum number of arguments:

Awful looking and definitely not a best practice:

```
class Constructor extends Predecessor {
  constructor(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) {
    super(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z);
  }
}
```

I, of course, don't like it.

So, is it just Babelify/Babel or is this not allowed in ES2015 ? Is there something I could do to improve this (contribute to Babelify)? or should I just go back the old implementation ?

In case you are wondering my compilation process:

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js ./src/index.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]",
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: "*removing super throws an error ("super must be called")*" - that's a [known Babel bug](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7248), it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so `Predecessor` gets executed something like if you did: `new Predecessor([arguments])`: array within array

Well, that is what you wrote: `super(arguments)` passes the whole object into one parameter. You'd need to write `super(...arguments)` to pass the arguments through as they came. Or even better, don't use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) any more in ES6 but rest parameters:

```
class Constructor extends Predecessor {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

(or just omit the `constructor` method if you don't do anything else, as this is the default behaviour).

Comment: I did not know that was possible